# Not writing in files

Tags: python

I have written this code but it is not writing the data in the file.

```
import random
import datetime
while(True):
    def getdate():
        import datetime
        return datetime.datetime.now()

    #will take input from the user
    userInput = int(input("What do you want to do: \n 1) Spin minecraft Challenge Wheel \n 2) Spin Pro Challenge Wheel \n 3) Retrieve Data \n Write there serial number to choose: \n"))

    if userInput==1:
        minecraftchallengewheel = ["Do nothing", "Kill ender dragon in 1 minute in any gamemode", "download herobrine mod", "delete your favorite world", "Kill wither in 1 minute", "Be friend of wither"]

        minecraftchallengechoice = random.choice(minecraftchallengewheel)
        minecraftchallengechoicelist = minecraftchallengechoice

        print(f"You have to {minecraftchallengechoice}")
        print("Do you want to log the data? (y/n) \n")
        minecraftchallengeyn = input()

        if minecraftchallengeyn == "y":
            with open("challengelog.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(str([str(getdate())]) + ": " + minecraftchallengechoicelist + "\n")
```

Comment: Have you verified that execution is reaching the `f.write` line? And have you tried using an absolute path to ensure it's being written to the directory that you expect?

Comment: Simplest solution: add print() at every line where something important happens, with descriptive text on what happening there. For example, after `userInput = int(....)` you write `print("User entered", userInput)`, after `minecratchallengeyn = input()` write `print("User answers on the question about 'save the data'", minecraftchallengeyn)` and so on. You'll see what the problem is

Comment: Does your code raise any errors? Does it create a file but not write to it? Have you single-stepped through the code to verify it executes as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked here.

```
import random
import datetime

def getdate():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

while(True):
    #will take input from the user
    userInput = int(input("What do you want to do: \n 1) Spin minecraft Challenge Wheel \n 2) Spin Pro Challenge Wheel \n 3) Retrieve Data \n Write there serial number to choose: \n"))

    if userInput==1:
        minecraftchallengewheel = ["Do nothing", "Kill ender dragon in 1 minute in any gamemode", "download herobrine mod", "delete your favorite world", "Kill wither in 1 minute", "Be friend of wither"]

        minecraftchallengechoice = random.choice(minecraftchallengewheel)
        minecraftchallengechoicelist = minecraftchallengechoice

        print(f"You have to {minecraftchallengechoice}")
        print("Do you want to log the data? (y/n) \n")
        minecraftchallengeyn = input()

        if minecraftchallengeyn == "y":
            try:
                with open("challengelog.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write(str([str(getdate())]) + ": " + minecraftchallengechoicelist + "\n")
            except IOError:
                print('Fail to open the file')
```

The challengelog.txt file.

```
['2021-08-23 11:55:54.880117']: Kill ender dragon in 1 minute in any gamemode
['2021-08-23 11:56:39.066004']: Kill ender dragon in 1 minute in any gamemode
['2021-08-23 11:57:02.427010']: download herobrine mod
['2021-08-23 12:01:23.214895']: Be friend of wither
```